# SQL using WHERE to filter out data and keep the rest

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL I want to select from

It has a column for site and then location

I want to select all sites and locations but with the exception of a few

the data looks like this:

```
Site  Location 
Foo    ABC
Foo    DEF
Bar    GHI
Bar    JKL
Bar    LNO
Toe    PQR
```

I want to select Foo when the location is not ABC and 
select Bar when the Location is JKL

The results I want to achieve is like so:

```
Site  Location 
Foo    DEF
Bar    JKL
Toe    PQR
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
       WHERE ( (Site  like 'Foo' and Location not like 'ABC')
            or (Site  like 'Bar' and Location like 'JKL')
             or Site  like '%')
```

But the results I get contain the Location I want to filter out

Comment: `or site like '%'` will return everything.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That didnt work for me

Comment: Try changing last or to `or (Site  like '%' and Site not like 'Foo' and Site not 'Bar')`

Comment: Thanks @AlexBaranowski I did the following and it worked 
       WHERE ((Site  like 'Foo' and Location not like 'ABC')
            or (Site  like 'Bar' and Location like 'JKL')
             or (Site  like '%' and Sit not like 'Foo' and Site not like 'Bar')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (Site  like 'Foo' and Location not like 'ABC') OR
      (Site  like 'Bar' and Location like 'JKL') OR
      (Site not like 'Foo' and Site not like 'Bar');
```

I am not sure why you are using `LIKE` for the logic.  `=` and `IN` seem more appropriate:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (Site = 'Foo' and Location <> 'ABC') OR
      (Site = 'Bar' and Location = 'JKL') OR
      (Site NOT IN ('Foo', 'Bar'));
```

Comment: I use LIKE because in my real data I use wildcards to get the site and location names but yeah I would use = if I wasn't

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (Site = 'Foo' and Location <> 'ABC') OR
  (Site = 'Bar' and Location = 'JKL') OR
  (Site <> 'Foo' AND Site <> 'Bar');
```

Comment: ..missing context... please provide.